# Rails - How to show attribute of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple app where I have a list of client names and a list of savings amounts on another model. In this scenario a user has_many :savings and a saving belongs_to :user. When adding a new savings record you can choose the client that the saving pertains to via collection_select drop down. The code looks like this:

```
collection_select(:saving, :client_id, Client.all, :id, :name)
```

That part works just fine, it takes that name from the list and saves the record to that client. However, after saving and going back to the savings show page it lists the client as the client_id instead of the client name, which is to be expected since the code on my show page is:

```
<%= @saving.client_id %>
```

My question is, how do I list the client name instead of the client_id on the show page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@saving.client.name
```

Should work

Comment: that works great actually, thanks. So another question then, I am using best_in_place as a gem for in place editing on the show page. It's supposed to be written like 'best_in_place @object, :symbol, :options'. Any idea how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Never used that gem actually but it could be: best_in_place(@saving, :saving_attribute_to_edit_in_place, :best_in_place_options). If you want to edit Client attributes in the same form you should give a look at rails nested_forms.

Comment: Thanks again, didn't even know about nested_forms until you mentioned it. SO much to learn.

Comment: @FattRyan, true but it's so rewarding you would never want to stop! ;)